# Create a notebook from several md files

Tags: pdf, directory, markdown

I'm new to **Stack Overflow**.

I write a lot. So I created different `.md` files in different directories.

Now I wanna create a notebook(it doesn't matter in `.pdf` format or another `.md`) from all the `md` files but I have some problems:

1. It will be messy I guess
2. I don't know how to do so

I wanted to know if there is a way to do it in a tidy way :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your post is tagged for r-markdown, so I am going to show you how to do it the r-markdown way.

You can create an index.Rmd file (this doesn't have to be named index.rmd) that links to other r markdowns.

In your index file, add a code chunk with the following bit of code:

````
```{r child = 'children/summary.Rmd'}

```
````

This will knit what you have in the `summary.Rmd` into `index.Rmd`. For this example, I put `summary.Rmd` into a sub directory called "children".

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: OMG! I'm so sorry I didn't mean r-markdown, I don't even know it

I delete the tag now

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the fastest and the most hassle-free way for you to start with the notebook is to use one of the myriads of [static generators](https://www.staticgen.com) available (for example, [MkDocs Material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/)) or proceed with an application for taking notes (for example, [Notable](https://notable.md), [Boost Note](https://boostnote.io), and [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org))

Comment: Thank you so much but it wan't what I was looking for
I'm looking for something to create a single md file from several md files(which is organized like 1-something.md 2-something.md 3-something.md , ....)